# AppScripts (Google Sheets) returning NaN

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with my AppScripts. I am attempting to automate an ELO Formula, it returns NaN every time. I get no errors, and I am extremely confused, does anyone have a solution?

`

```
function Loop() {
  const Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3Test');

  var EndRow = Sheet2.getLastRow();

for (var i = 2; i <= EndRow; i++)
{
  Utilities.sleep(12)
  var Team1ELO = Sheet2.getRange(i, 10).getValue()
  var Team2ELO = Sheet2.getRange(i, 11).getValue()
  var ExpectedResult = Sheet2.getRange(i, 12).getValue()
  var ActualResult = Sheet2.getRange(i, 13).getValue()
  var KFact = Sheet2.getRange(i, 14).getValue()



  var newELOVal = Sheet2.getRange(i, 8).getValue()
  var newELOVal2 = Sheet2.getRange(i, 9).getValue() 

if (newELOVal == "" & newELOVal2 == "" && Team1ELO != "" && Team2ELO != "" && KFact != "" && ActualResult != "" != ExpectedResult !="")
{

var TeamAELOOutput = Team1ELO + KFact * (ActualResult - ExpectedResult)

var TeamBELOOutput = (Team2ELO + (KFact * ((1 - ActualResult) - (1 - ExpectedResult)))) 

Sheet2.getRange(i, 8).setValue(TeamAELOOutput)
Sheet2.getRange(i, 9).setValue(TeamBELOOutput)


}




}
}
```

}

}
}

I tried to automate the ELO System by using a for loop and automating the ELO values.

Comment: Confirm that all the input values are numbers first.

Comment: I have confirmed that every input value is a number.

Comment: Maybe they appear as numbers but are actually strings. Normally this doesn't make a difference, but it really depends. Manually convert them to numbers to be sure.